# how to test changes to an installed package

Tags: python

I have installed a python package slimit and I have cloned the source code from github.

I am doing changes to this package in my local folders which I want to test (often) but I don't want to do allways python setup.py install.

My folder structure is:

../develop/slimit/src/slimit (contains package files)
../develop/test/test.py

I'm using eclipse + pydev + python 2.7, on linux

Should I run eclipse with "sudo rights"?

Even better, is there a way to import the local development package into my testing script?

Comment: can you not just import from the directories without installing?

Comment: no, the changed package is not installed. "from ../slimit import x" does not work

Comment: I mean unless there are reasons you have to use the setup.py script, add the package to your project folder in eclipse, make changes to that and import from that not the installed version

Comment: ok, that worked, thanks! for the record, the local package takes precedence over the system package.

Comment: yep, local scope always gets checked first. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working on a library you can use `python setup.py develop` instead of `install`. This will install the package into your local environment and keep it updated as you develop.

To be clear, if you use `develop` you don't have to run it again when you change your source files.

Comment: and I can have it wherever I like it?

Comment: Yes, this is best used with a virtualenv, because then when you want access to your lib you just activate the venv and you have it, updating as you go.